# does Blender have a Material Swatches panel showing all available materials?

Tags: materials

I'm a C4D user and it has a Materials Pallette. I can see a preview of all materials in the file and I can drag one onto an object. Does Blender have a similar window?

Answer (score 1):

It does, in the materials tab, and the arrow points to the droplist of all your materials. I never tried drag'n'drop, though, so you need to check it. This is from Blender 2.7x so the current version (2.9x) must have this much or more.
[image]

Comment: ok, that's very helpful. I wanted a quick way to select and switch colors on an object. I was doing it using nodes and multiple rgb ramp nodes but this is a great option. thank you so much! if you come across a way to display the materials without needing the drop down, please share. thanks for your help. I'm starting to really like Blender :)